# Meteor useraccounts watch state

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-useraccounts

I'm using Meteor useraccounts:bootstrap.
On my navbar i have btnLogin and btnLogOut. I want only my login button to show when im logged out, and only the logout button when im logged in.

My logic:

```
if (!error) {
    if (state === "signIn") {
      document.getElementById('btnLogin').style.display = 'none';
    }
    else if (state != 'signIn') {
      document.getElementById('btnLogOut').style.display = 'visible';
    }
```

How do i get my app to look for state without triggering an event/click?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're logged in, Meteor.userId() will return the _id of the current user.

So you can have something like this:

**page.html:**

```
{{#if isUserLoggedIn}}
      <<<<<show logout button >>>>>>
{{else}}
      <<<<<show login button >>>>>> 
{{/if}}
```

**page.js**

```
Template.page.helper({
     isUserLoggedIn: function(){
           if(Meteor.userId()){
                return true;
            }
          return false;
     }
});
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what i wanted and Meteoric!